# Por que no me aparece la division

Tags: c, division

Al estar haciendo este codigo en C, no me sale el resultado de la division, alguna idea de por que?

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {

    int asignaturas;
    int matriculas;


    scanf("%d" , asignaturas);
    scanf("%d" , matriculas);
    float media =  ((matriculas / asignaturas)*100);
    printf("Tu media es %f", media);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: La lectura de las variables está mal. Debes usar `&` delante de cada una (pues `scanf()` espera la dirección de la variable, para dejar allí el valor)

Comment: justo lo revisé y era eso, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int asignaturas;
int matriculas;


scanf("%d" , &asignaturas);
scanf("%d" , &matriculas);
float media =  ((matriculas / asignaturas)*100);
printf("Tu media es %f", &media);


return 0;
```

proba de esta manera, los parametros del scanf estan incompletos, te adjunto documentacion para que la revises si lo necesitas

https://documentation.help/C-Cpp-Reference/scanf.html

Comment: Con este código, no tienes problemas en la división matriculas / asignaturas y obtienes un int en lugar de un float que quieres?

Comment: directamente te expresa ese int como float. Por ejemplo si el resultado de (matriculas / asignaturas) te da 5 la media va a valer 500.00

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que actives y hagas caso a todas las advertencias de compilación de tu programa.

En tu caso, son éstas:

```
pr.c: In function ‘main’:
pr.c:10:13: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   10 |     scanf("%d" , asignaturas);
      |            ~^    ~~~~~~~~~~~
      |             |    |
      |             |    int
      |             int *
pr.c:11:13: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   11 |     scanf("%d" , matriculas);
      |            ~^    ~~~~~~~~~~
      |             |    |
      |             |    int
      |             int *
pr.c:10:5: warning: ‘asignaturas’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   10 |     scanf("%d" , asignaturas);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pr.c:11:5: warning: ‘matriculas’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   11 |     scanf("%d" , matriculas);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

¿Qué significa la siguiente advertencia?

> format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’

Significa que el formato `%d` en `scanf()` necesita como parámetro el puntero a un entero (`int *`) y tú has proporcionado un entero (`int`).

En otras palabras, `scanf()` necesita que le proporciones una dirección de memoria en la que guardar el entero que ha leído. De otra manera no podrá guardar el resultado obtenido.

Para hacerlo debes cambiar:

```
scanf("%d" , asignaturas);
```

Por:

```
scanf("%d" , &asignaturas);
```

---

Por último, vas a perder precisión en el cálculo y en cualquier combinación de `asignaturas` y `matriculas` vas a obtener como resultado `100`, exceptuando cuando `matriculas` sea `0`, en cuyo caso el resultado será `0` (estoy desechando combinaciones arbitrarias).

Eso es debido a que, por defecto, las operaciones entre variables enteras serán realizadas usando división entera.

Una forma de mejorar la precisión y que el resultado se almacene como entero podría ser cambiar:

```
float media =  ((matriculas / asignaturas)*100);
printf("Tu media es %f", &media);
```

Por:

```
int media =  matriculas * 100 / asignaturas;
printf("Tu media es %d\n", &media);
```

Pero si deseas almacenar el valor como coma flotante, entonces deberías convertir las variables a coma flotante antes de realizar las operaciones:

```
float media =  (float)matriculas * 100 / asignaturas;
printf("Tu media es %f\n", &media);
```

En cuanto el primer operando sea de coma flotante, el resto de operaciones también se realizarán en coma flotante, realizándose una conversión entre tipos cuando sea necesario.

---

Tu código podría quedar:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int asignaturas;
    int matriculas;

    puts("Introduzca el número de asignaturas:");
    scanf("%d" , &asignaturas);
    puts("Introduzca el número de matrículas:");
    scanf("%d" , &matriculas);

    float media =  (float)matriculas * 100 / asignaturas;
    printf("Tu media es %f\n", media);

    return 0;
}
```